# Showing $f(z)=|z|^{1/2}z$ is differentiable at $z=0$ but not holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis

Given  $f(z)=|z|^{1/2}z$, it is obviously complex differentiable at $z=0$ because $$f'(0)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{|z|^{1/2}z}{z}=0$$ I have done similar examples with $|z|^2$, but the $|z|^{1/2}$ is throwing me off because you cannot simply expand it like you would with $|z|^2$. How can I show that it is not holomorphic at $z=0$?

Also, what would be the set of all $z$ such that $f$ is complex differentiable? I assume I have to use Cauchy-Riemann equation, but again, I'm having trouble working with the $|z|^{1/2}$

Comment: Have you tried looking at the partial derivatives and determining where they obey the Cauchy Riemann equations?

Comment: One approach might be (not sure if it works): since $g(z)=z^2$ is holomorphic, consider $g\circ f(z)$. I believe this fails to be holomorphic, so $f(z)$ is not holomorphic. I’m not $100\%$ sure this is valid (though I am reasonably sure), but it at least provides a nice heuristic.

Comment: @Kevin What for? And surely you are aware there exists no continuous square root in a neighborhood of the origin?

Comment: @Did Mind blank. Yes I was aware, I had a bad day :-(

Comment: @Kevin No problem. Next day surely will be better... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holomorphicity at $0$ means that it's complex-differentiable in a neighbourhood
of $0$. But it's not complex-differentiable other than at $0$.

For the C-R equations, one has $f(x+iy)=u+iv$
where
$$u=x(x^2+y^2)^{1/4}$$
and
$$v=y(x^2+y^2)^{1/4}.$$
Then
$$u_x=(x^2+y^2)^{1/4}+\frac{x^2}{2(x^2+y^2)^{3/4}}
=\frac{3x^2+2y^2}{2(x^2+y^2)^{3/4}}$$
and similarly,
$$v_y=\frac{2x^2+3y^2}{2(x^2+y^2)^{3/4}}.$$
These are different at nonzero points on the $x$-axis, so $f$ isn't
complex-differentiable there, and so not in any neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: shouldn't $u=x\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{1/4}$? since $|z|$ itself is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: @YaG Thanks${}$!

Comment: Here's something about the logic of all this troubles me and I can't figure it out. So, we want to argue that $f$ is not holomorphic at $z=0$. By way of contradiction, assume $f$ is holomorphic at $z=0$. Then it is complex differentiable on an open nhbd of $0$, which is to say(?) that it satisfies the CR equations on that nhbd of $0$. But we can't even plug in $x=y=0$ into the CR equations, because we get division by division. This can't be the contradiction that we seek...What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Substistute $z = x+iy$

Separate your function into real parts and imaginary parts.

$|z|^\frac12$ is strictly real

$|z| = (x^2 + y^2)^\frac 12\\
|z|^{\frac 12} = (x^2 + y^2)^\frac 14\\
|z|^{\frac 12}z = (x^2 + y^2)^\frac 14(x+iy)$

$f(x+iy) = u+iv\\
u = (x^2+y^2)^\frac 14x\\
v = (x^2+y^2)^\frac 14y$

Do these satisfy they Cauchy-Reimann equations?

$\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac {\partial v}{\partial y}\\
\frac {\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac {\partial v}{\partial x}$

Comment: Got it! However, your $u$ and $v$ looks wrong.